# Javascript - Downloading all Media on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, download, media

As a side project, I made an image gallery that parses a page for media elements and displays them neatly on a page. I'd like to create the option to download every media object with just one action.

So imagine a page has 50 images on it, each one not hosted locally. Is there a way to start a download where all 50 images are bundled together into one folder/tar?

Bonus points: At this point, all the media will have already been downloaded/loaded onto the page. It'd be awesome if this download action doesn't need to re-fetch all the data for each object.

Comment: with javascript - i don't think so.

Comment: @Cracker0dks i do think so!

Comment: One possible method client-side: notify viewer to right-click , select "Save As..." --> select "Webpage, complete". Possible js method: create `blob` of single page containing all required elements , provide for download of page at `a` element click.

Answer (score 0):

Alright to do such a thing you would need a canvas and a 2d context:

```
var
    mediaCanvas = document.getElementById('mediacanvas'),
    mediaImages = document.getElementsByClassName('mediaimage'),
    ctx = document.getElementById('drawcanvas').getContext('2d'),
    rawImages = [], tmpImage, i
;
```

Then for each image you would do something like

```
for (i = 0; i < mediaImages.length; i++) {
    tmpImage = mediaImages[i];
    // resize canvas to image size
    canvas.width = tmpImage.width;
    canvas.height = tmpImage.height;
    ctx.drawImage(tmpImage, 0, 0);
    // get base64 image data
    rawImages.push(canvas.toDataURL('jpg')); // one could detect the original image type here
}
```

Now you've the base64 encoded image data in `rawImages`. Next we need to turn the data into some proper binary `ArrayBuffer` using one of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript).

When this is done you can either build your own tar/zip/whatever packer, or use something like [pako.js](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) to assemble an archive containing your data. The last thing left to allow the user to download the data is to create a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.Blob) from the resulting `ArrayBuffer` and a corresponding [ObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Example_for_creating_a_URL_to_a_typed_array_using_a_blob) to it.

Comment: That's intense. Thanks a lot for your response! I'll try it out this weekend when I continue this project and update this post with my results.